# Autoregressive modeling with excluding lags

Tags: autoregressive-models

In terms of autoregressive modeling, has anyone ever seen it done with excluding some of the immediately preceding lags?

That is, has anyone ever seen it done with n=(not 1) under the summation sign??

Any pointers to it in the literature would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely acceptable. You can still think of it as an AR(n) process, with n=1 under the summation. It's just that certain autoregressive coefficients will have the value of zero. In fact, you can force this sparsity in a systematic way by adding an L1 penalty, akin to the Lasso Regression problem. For more down that path, you can check out this link for example:
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/papers/arLasso.pdf